# Как вытащить из строки определённое кол-во символов?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Помогите, пожалуйста, вытащить из строки c помощью регулярных выражений такого вида

```
   string s = "http://сайт.ру/simple_captcha/simple_captcha?simple_captcha_key=ab1cfa3e1018bfdc72c7bcc040ae4bcd5b115f79&amp;time=1431170052";
```

Вот эту часть: `ab1cfa3e1018bfdc72c7bcc040ae4bcd5b115f79`

Answer (score 5):

Есть несколько вариантов, в зависимости от того, что вы знаете о строке,
которую вы хотите вытащить.

1. Просто взять подстроку по началу и концу;
2. Выделить с помощью регулярного выражения;
3. Распарсить URL и взять параметр URL.

В вашем случае нужно использовать, очевидно, последний вариант.

Распарсить URL вы можете следующим образом:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://server:8080/func2/SubFunc2?query=somevalue");

// имя хоста и порт "server:8080".
string hostpart = myUri.Authority;

// путь "/func2/SubFunc2?query=somevalue".
string pathpart = myUri.PathAndQuery;

// элементы пути { "/", "func2/", "sunFunc2" }.
string[] pathsegments = myUri.Segments;

// запрос "?query=somevalue".
string querystring = myUri.Query;
```

После этого вы с помощью HttpUtility парсите строку запроса:

```
var options = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);
```

В `options["simple_captcha_key"]` и есть то, что вы ищете.

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте так:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://site.ru/simple_captcha" +
     "?simple_captcha_key=ab1cfa3e1018bfdc72c7bcc040ae4bcd5b115f79" +
     "&time=1431170052");
var q = uri.Query;
var parts = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(q);
var r = parts["simple_captcha_key"];
```

Вам придётся подключить System.Web.

Comment: а простым Regex'ом нельзя вытащить? ссылка хранится в строковой переменной и не парсится ниоткуда.просто есть строка с ссылкой и мне нужно получить всё что идёт после "simple_captcha_key=" до " ; "

Comment: а чем этот метод плох?

Comment: ничем не плох, просто хочу сделать получение данных через регулярные выражения

Comment: поправьте тогда текст вопроса

Comment: @inkorpus: Регулярные выражения сложны, и вы можете пропустить какой-нибудь крайний случай. Например, в адресе можно закодировать имя пользователя и пароль (`http://vasya:parol@www.site.com/vasya`) — будет ли ваша регулярка поддерживать такое?

Answer (score 3):

Заточить регулярку под Вашу задачу не составляет труда:

```
string s = "http://сайт.ру/simple_captcha/simple_captcha?simple_captcha_key=ab1cfa3e1018bfdc72c7bcc040ae4bcd5b115f79&amp;time=1431170052";
var regex = new Regex(@"simple_captcha_key=((\d|\w)+)&");
var matches = regex.Matches(s);
if(matches.Count > 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", matches[0].Groups[1]);
```

Для примера выше, даже следующая регулярка пойдёт:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"=((\d|\w)+)&");
```

Правда, на мой взгляд, 2 других ответа, которые не используют регулярки, куда лучше.